# Rails 4 has_many association several primary key ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I want to be able to join a model to a relations table by looking at several ids on the primary key.
This is how I'm trying to do it. I have a has_many through association as described below:

```
class Pro < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_relationships, lambda { |pro| where(pro_id: [pro.id] + pro.authorized_pros) }
  has_many :clients, through: :client_relationships
end
```

ClientRelationship is a basic relation table with no default scope and Client is the same class as Pro except it's in the opposite way.

I'm trying to apply a scope on the `has_many :clients` generated methods. The thing is that when I do `pro.clients` I get the following query (given `pro.id` = 1 and `pro.authorized_pros` = [2, 3])

```
SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` INNER JOIN `client_relationships` ON `clients`.`id` = `client_relationships`.`client_id` WHERE `client_relationships`.`pro_id` = 1 AND `client_relationships`.`pro_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
```

We can see that the last portion of SQL (starting from `AND`) is generated by Rails.

Is there a way I could **disable** this behavior? Or maybe another solution?

**EDIT** : I need the two `has_many` relations on the Pro model because I use its generated methods
**EDIT 2** : moved the scope to the relations has_many :client_relationships

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the relation depends on the two rules, but you can try [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) part to generate the query:

```
ClientRelationship.arel_table[:pro_id].in(pro.authorized_pros | [ pro.id ])
```

Comment: I need to be able to use `pro.clients` transparently. This `arel` query is the same as the `where` query in the scope